# Laravel session expires before user gets logged out

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication

I have a persons table which is related to users table, Each user can have one or more person, The purpose is to make all family persons log in with the same login details (It's not my idea) .. So after a user logs in he's redirected to select which person in the family he is. After some person is selected I store the id of that person in session using

```
    Session::put('loggedPersonId',$id)
```

And I restore this id each time a request is made and a user is logged in. The problem is that the session expires before the user is logged out.
I need someway to force the session to keep loggedPersonId as long as the user is logged in whatever the lifetime of the session is

===== UPDATE =====
This problem only occurs when a user logs in with the remember me box checked .. The loggedPersonId lasts until the minutes I set in session.lifetime config option ends while the user keeps logged in until he logs out by himself .. 
But If a user logged in without having remember me checked everything works fine , the user gets logged out at the same time loggedPersonId gets cleared after  minutes

Comment: How do you restore that id from session? Maybe you're popping out the value, so you're clearing it yourself?

Comment: @Omranic ,  No I don't pop it .. I use ` Session::get('loggedAccountId') ` .. The problem only occurs when I check the remember me checkbox when logging in .. But otherwise the user gets logged out and the session data I saved gets cleared at the same time (i.e after <lifetime> minutes I set in session config file)